# Spark AR Studio and Visual Studio Code integration

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to develop Spark AR scripts using Visual Studio Code and the integration provided by the [official extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SparkAR.spark-ar-studio).

I have followed the steps from the [official tutorial](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/scripting/vs-code-extension) and autocomplete and other features such as getting the Spark console, graph visualizer and also the watchers are working fine (just had to make sure to check that both the VS Code extension and the Spark AR Studio were working on the same version).

However, when it comes to debugging I am not able to make it work. Selecting the option **Run and Debug** as suggested in the tutorial opens a dropdown menu with several options, from which I choose **Spark AR Studio**, after doing that nothing seems to happen.

Another issue that I noticed is that when I make the connection with AR Spark Studio, the workspace doesn't open as it is supposed to (as mentioned in https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/scripting/vs-code-extension#using-the-extension), maybe the debugging issue is related with this.

So the question is, is there any extra configuration step that has to be done or I am missing something? I would like to be able to set up breakpoints and watch the state of the variables.

Comment: I cannot find how to debug it as well, and like you, I don't see a project in the drop-down, as mentioned in the article, and nothing happens if I select "Spark AR Studio" in the debug drop-down :/ Did you find how to debug it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I could not make further progress on the topic. There is however a new version (v130) of both Spark AR Studio and the VS Code extension, maybe that fixes something even though I haven't tried.